# Wrapping Geojson data across date line in Openlayers

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-6

I am using OpenLayers to map earthquakes using the USGS dataset available at:

```
https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_month.geojson
```

I am adding layers and configuring the view like so:

```
var map = new Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    new TileLayer({
      source: new OSM()
    }),
    new ImageLayer({
      opacity: 0.3,
      source: raster
    }),
    new WebGLPointsLayer({
      source: new VectorSource({
        url: "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_month.geojson",
        format: new GeoJSON(),
        attributions: 'USGS'
      })
    })
  ],
  view: new View({
    center: fromLonLat([103.8198, 1.3521]),
    zoom: 1
  })
});
```

My view is set so that at zoom level 1, the date line is included in the extent. The USGS data does not render to the right of the date line. I understand that this is because the VectorSource's default extent is [-180, -90, 180, 90]. My question is, how can I change that extent to the extent of the map view so that data renders on the other side of the the date line?

It seems like the best approach would be to intercept the coordinates of the USGS data and add a transformation to the lon coordinate, maybe through [ol/proj.transform](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_proj.html#.transform) or [ol/proj.transformExtent](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_proj.html#.transformExtent), but I haven't been able to find the openlayers data object that contains the coordinates nor the way to apply a map or transformation to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vectors layers use the view projection which unless specified is EPSG:3857 centered on the Greenwich meridian

You could try defining a spherical mercator centered on the dateline

```
proj4.defs('sphmerc180', '+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=180.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs');
register(proj4);

var sphmerc180 = getProjection('sphmerc180');
sphmerc180.setExtent(getProjection('EPSG:3857').getExtent());
sphmerc180.setGlobal(true);
```

then use that as the view projection

```
  view: new View({
    projection: sphmerc180,
    center: fromLonLat([103.8198, 1.3521], sphmerc180),
    zoom: 1
  })
```

Comment: This feels like it is going in the right direction. The data now progresses throughout the view, but now the entire map is 1/4 the original size and the view is no longer centered at [103.8198, 1.3521]. It is centered on the date line.

Comment: Setting the projection extent to match EPSG:3857 should fix that.

Comment: Now the basemap is nicely centered in the right location as it was when I began, but the data is rendered between [0, 360], i.e. from the prime meridian to the prime meridian.

Comment: If I adjust +lon_0=180.0 to +lon_0=103.8198, the data aligns, but perhaps now I am going the long way round to the solution.

Comment: You can center the projection on any longitude but currently you can only render with WebGL within one world of that projection (unlike VectorLayer the source's wrapX setting has no effect).  Until that is supported I think the projection change is the best workaround, although if you were also using vector tiles that would be a problem as vector tiles designed for one projection don't work with another.