# Can a Heapmap Layer wrap like the Vector Layer in openlayers 6

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-6

I want to render Heatmap in openlayers 6. With this example from openlayers: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/earthquake-custom-symbol.html.

If I change the layer type from Vector to Heapmap, the content will NOT wrap (repeat) when I move  the map in one direction. How can I make the Heapmap layer wrap like a Vector layer?

Comment: Heatmap in version 6 uses a WebGL renderer which currently has no support for wrap (even if the source specifies it).  If you need a map of the Pacific region one option would be to change the center the projection as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60793481/wrapping-geojson-data-across-date-line-in-openlayers

Comment: Hi @Mike, Thanks for the comment. I'm looking for an easy solution. Will switching to openlayer-5 help, then?

Comment: Yes, heatmaps wrap in version 5  https://openlayers.org/en/v5.3.0/examples/heatmap-earthquakes.html

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try.